# limiting the cpu count for a user

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu-usage

To limit the number of available cores for a user I have decided to use cgroup. So, by creating a group, I have to set a number for `cpu.shares`. Assume there are 32 cores in the system and I want to limit a user to 4 cores only. What is the correct value for that parameter?

As far as I understand, I have to use 400 since the total cpu time is 3200. Am I correct?

Comment: Have you had a look at this question : http://serverfault.com/questions/603861/limit-user-to-n-cpu-cores

Comment: I was looking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5106 So what is the difference between nice and cgroup?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should learn that `cpu.shares` does not set *hard* limit to number of cores. It is generic parameter that is used to account consumed CPU resources in CFS scheduler.

I.e. if there are two apps in the system both spent 1 second of CPU time, CFS will set their `vruntime` to 10<sup>9</sup>/`cpu.shares`, so they they both need more CPU time, they have equal chances to get it.

Now, if you adjust `cpu.shares` to smaller values (i.e `128`) for first application, it will get `vruntime` = 10<sup>9</sup>/128 = 7.8 * 10<sup>6</sup>, while second one (with unadjusted value of shares) will get `vruntime` = 10<sup>9</sup>/1024 = 0.9 * 10<sup>6</sup>. The process with lesser `vruntime` will be picked to execute on CPU first, so second app can execute for 7 more seconds unless CPU will given to the first app.

Note that this priorities only work in presence of second CPU-greedy app. If only apps of "limited" user are working, CFS scheduler will put them on CPUs, so they can occupy all of 32 cores.

Finally, answering initial question, your task is purely mathematical:

```
     x        4
 -------- = ----
 1024 + x    32
```

You should set `cpu.shares` to **146**.

Comment: That didn't limit the cpu counts. Please see my new topic at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270938